# Underfull \hbox warning about alignement in a csvsimple table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable, csv, csvsimple

The following `csvsimple` table keeps returning warnings of the type: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines`:

```
\csvreader[no head, longtable=|p{\dimexpr 0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr 0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr 0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr 0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr 0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|, table head=\hline, late after line=\\\hline]
{gantt/GanttChart.csv}
{1=\one, 2=\two, 3=\three, 4=\four, 5=\five}
{\one & \two & \three & \four & \five}%
```

I know that `\raggedright` can fix it, but I couldn't guess where to put it exactly inside the `p{}`?

Here are the first lines (it contains 14 lines in total) of my `csv` file:

```
Task Mode,Task Name,Duration,Start,Finish
Manually Scheduled,task1,3.3 mons,Mon 01/06/15,Mon 31/08/15
Manually Scheduled,task2,34 days,Wed 15/07/15,Mon 31/08/15
Manually Scheduled,task3,11 days,Tue 01/09/15,Tue 15/09/15
```

Comment: Can we see a few lines of `GanttChart.csv`?

Comment: @egreg I've updated my question.

Comment: It's not really surprising that “Manually Scheduled” set at `0.2\linewidth` produces an underfull box. Why not simply five left aligned columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typesetting in narrow columns is best done with `\raggedright`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Task Mode,Task Name,Duration,Start,Finish
Manually Scheduled,task1,3.3 mons,Mon 01/06/15,Mon 31/08/15
Manually Scheduled,task2,34 days,Wed 15/07/15,Mon 31/08/15
Manually Scheduled,task3,11 days,Tue 01/09/15,Tue 15/09/15
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,array}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\csvreader[
  no head,
  tabular=
    |*{5}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr 0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.2\arrayrulewidth}|},
  table head=\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline
]{\jobname.csv}
  {1=\one, 2=\two, 3=\three, 4=\four, 5=\five}
  {\one & \two & \three & \four & \five}

\end{document}
```

Note the adjustment due to taking care of the six vertical rules, each `\arrayrulewidth` wide, to divide among the five columns (6/5=1.2).

[image]

As usual, `filecontents` is used just for making the example self-contained. I don't think you need `longtable`, but you can change the code as you wish.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I got rid of all the warnings except the last one, which persists in the line corresponding to `{\one & \two & \three & \four & \five}`. And btw, I'm using longtable, because without it I cannot get an array which takes more than a page (is there another way to do so?). Also this last warning seems similar to this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166917/underfull-vbox-badness-10000-detected-at-line

Comment: @h4k1m I too saw tha `Underfull \vbox` message, but it's nature is different from the `Underfull \hbox` messages you got. It has something to do with how `csvsimple` implements its interface to `longtable`, but I'm not sure what it is: the warning is typical of misplaced ``\\``.

Comment: Ok I'll ignore it then. For me, this issue is considered fixed!