# Make a csvsimple longtable appear on the list of tables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, csvsimple

My question is somewhat related to my previous one (See [Underfull \hbox warning about alignement in a csvsimple table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298230/underfull-hbox-warning-about-alignement-in-a-csvsimple-table)

I need to add a `caption` to a `csvsimple`-generated `longtable`, but if I enclose my csv table inside a `\table` element, it will take just one page and be truncated at the end (even though it would appear on the `list of tables`).

My aim is to have this table appearing on my `List of tables`.

Is there any parameter of `csvreader` that allows it to affect a caption to a table generated with it, so that it would appear on the list of tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Task Mode,Task Name,Duration,Start,Finish
Manually Scheduled,task1,3.3 mons,Mon 01/06/15,Mon 31/08/15
Manually Scheduled,task2,34 days,Wed 15/07/15,Mon 31/08/15
Manually Scheduled,task3,11 days,Tue 01/09/15,Tue 15/09/15
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,array,longtable}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\section{Test}

\noindent
\csvreader[
  no head,
  longtable=
    |*{5}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr 0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.2\arrayrulewidth}|},
  table head=\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline,
  late after last line=\\\hline\caption{My nice table}
]{\jobname.csv}
  {1=\one, 2=\two, 3=\three, 4=\four, 5=\five}
  {\one & \two & \three & \four & \five}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can always create the `longtable` head and foot *outside* the `\csvreader`, if more control is needed.

Comment: Perfect, adding `late after last line=\\\hline\caption{My nice table}` did it.